# simple integral query

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm considering the integral (or antiderivative) of $\frac{1}{5x+4}$. I would argue that we can take out the factor of ${1/5}$. From their you could arrive at 2 answers by using the 'derivative of the bottom is equal to the top' rule- one of which is $1/5ln(x+4/5)+C$ which isn't correct but why?

Comment: It is correct.${}$

Comment: Your answer differs by a constant from the "official" answer. Since each answer has an arbitrary constant of integration, they are both right. To take care of situations where $x\lt -4/5$, you should have absolute value signs around $x+4/5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take out a factor of $1/5$ you will get:

$$\frac{1}{5x+4} = \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{x+\frac{4}{5}}\right)$$

Then integrating by the log rule:

$$\int \frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{x+\frac{4}{5}}\right)dx = \frac{1}{5}\ln\left(x + \frac{4}{5}\right) + C$$

The only thing you missed is your arbitrary constant $C$. Other than that you are correct.

**EDIT**

doing it the other way:

$$\int \frac{1}{5x+4}dx = \frac{1}{5}\ln|5x+4| + C$$

This is equal to your original answer:

$$\frac{1}{5}\ln\left(x + \frac{4}{5}\right) = \frac{1}{5}\ln\left(\frac{5x + 4}{5}\right) = \frac{1}{5}\left(\ln\left(5x + 4\right) - \ln\left(5\right)\right) = \frac{1}{5}\ln|5x+4| + C$$

Instead your constant here is $-\frac{\ln{5}}{5}$

Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Don't forget the $\text{d}x$! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{dx}{5x+4}=\frac15\ln|5x+4|+K$$
$$=\frac15\left(\ln5+\ln\left|x+\frac45\right|\right)+K$$

$$=\frac15\left(\ln\left|x+\frac45\right|\right)+K'$$ where $K'=K+\dfrac{\ln5}5$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{1}{5x+4}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{5}\ln|\,5x+4\,|+C$$

General rule: $$\int\frac{1}{ax+b}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{a}\cdot \ln|\,ax+b\,|+C$$